# How to open a keyboard with lossing focus from parent

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a problem and i not find answer in google.

I open a keyboard with button:

```
private void openKeyboard() {
        keyboardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 3);
            }
        });

    }
```

But my layout going crap after keyboard is visible. How to open it with lost any parent from parent?

Answer (score 0):

try with this snippet..

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
    linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

or try this

In your manifest file, try adding the following to the `<activity>` that you want to show the keyboard when the activity starts:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"or "stateAlwaysVisible"
```

or try this too..

```
        youredittext.requestFocus();
        youredittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(youredittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```